# List all data from database using asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to asp.net mvc 2.0.I have a question about listing data from database using asp.net mvc.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ListEmployee() {
       UserModels emp = new UserModels();
        emp.EmployeeList = (List<tblEmployee_Employee>)Session["list"];
        return View(emp);
}
```

**Model**

```
 public class GetEmployee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the view page employee.aspx page but I do not know how to write code in this view page.

please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC views need to be strongly typed to the model you are passing to them. So in your case you are passing a `UserModels` instance to your view. Assuming you already have a master page and you want to display in a table the list of employees you might have something along the lines of:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.UserModels>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% foreach (var employee in Model.EmployeeList) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(employee.name) %></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(employee.sex) %></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(employee.email) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

or even better, define a reusable display template that will automaticall be rendered for each item of the `EmployeeList` collection property (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/GetEmployee.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" 
%>

<tr>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.name) %></td>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.sex) %></td>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.email) %></td>
</tr>
```

and then in your main view simply reference this template:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.UserModels>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmployeeList)
        </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Now you no longer need any `foreach` loops (as ASP.NET MVC will automatically render the display template if the property is a collection property following standard naming conventions) and also you have a reusable display template for your model.